# Add tabcontrol to dynamically created tab control in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I've a tabcontrol on my page with 2 tabs. Now I want to create another tabcontrol dynamically and want to add the existing tab control to dynamically created tab control tabs.

Is is possible? I'm not able to add this.

Here is my code:

```
       TabControl tbdynamic = new TabControl();
       TabPage tbpaagedynamic = new TabPage();
       tbpaagedynamic.Controls.Add(statictabcontrol);
       tbdynamic.TabPages.Add(tbpaagedynamic);
```

Any idea?

Comment: I think, You just do not see it, because You set no tabber-text ( so the tab is not visible ). Try to set at least this or/and another color. I was adding tab pages all time, without any errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is posiible.
Add dynamic tab to Form :

```
this.Controls.Add(tbdynamic);
```

example

```
TabControl tbdynamic = new TabControl();
tbdynamic.Height = 200;
tbdynamic.Width = 200;
TabPage mPage = new TabPage();
mPage.Text = "Test Page";
tbdynamic.TabPages.Add(mPage);

mPage.Controls.Add(statictabcontrol);

statictabcontrol.Top = 0;
statictabcontrol.Left = 0;
this.Controls.Add(tbdynamic);
```

Comment: Hi Sameer thanks for the reply. I tried the way you said, but it is not displaying any tab.

Comment: Edited answer check now.

Comment: Still it is not working. Even it is not displaying existing (statictabontrol) tab. When I try to add dynamic tab control to another dynamic tab control it is working.

Comment: Check top and left property of static tab control.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the bringToFrontMethod() at the end of adding it to your Window.

tbdynamic.BringToFRont();